# get all files from local drive path using javascript or angularjs with out using file tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

am trying to access my local path to read files and store in the File object. Am not able to find a suitable way. please help me.
                const testFolder = 'C:/Users/AmazePC9/Desktop/test/';
                const fs = require('fs');

```
            fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
                console.log(file);
            })
            var fs = require('fs');
            var files =fs.readdirSync('C:/Users/AmazePC9/Desktop/test/');

            var file = new File("C:/Users/AmazePC9/Desktop/test/");
```

am using pure javascript or angularjs function.
am getting errors like, can't read 'fs' and 'require' is not function.

please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new file in client side ? `fs` is not available client side and you can not write files to directories of user file system.

Comment: i just want to get files from some folder path and store to file object array.. without file tag element.
the above is what i have tried to get  files